# How could I go about getting distinct field counts in Azure Search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have an index with around 35 million documents.  When a user issues a query with any combination of search words and filters, I need to get a count of unique values on another field.  The purpose is to answer the question "How many unique (field x) are there with a given query?".

I'm pretty sure that Azure Search doesn't have any capability to do this, so I thought I would try to do another query where I select just the field I want to count distinct values of, but I think this would be very time consuming with such a large index.  I'm also under the impression that I can only skip at max 100,000 records, which would make it impossible for me to do this if a query returned more than 100k results.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Search doesn't directly support distinct count of values today. In order to support it in a single query combined with `$filter`, it would either have to be supported as a new facet type, or maybe with a combination of `$count` and `$filter` where the field being counted is the key field (note that `$count` and `$filter` can't be combined today).

Feel free to add distinct count to the [Azure Search feedback forum](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search) to help prioritize the feature.

**Original Answer**

If you wanted a count of documents per unique value, you could use facets. For example, if you're searching for shoes under $100 dollars and you want to know, out of the hits, how many shoes of each color there are, you would do this:

```
GET /indexes/products/docs?search=shoes&$filter=price+lt+100&facet=color&api-version=2015-02-28
```

The response will contain a `@search.facets` property that contains buckets for each unique value along with a count. You can find more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798927.aspx) and [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-faceted-navigation/).

Comment: actually,  I use facets and understand them we'll enough.  I don't think they can solve this problem though.  The field that I want to get a unique count of will have millions of unique values.  Even if that wasn't the case,  I want the total number of unique values, not a count of documents for each unique value.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?